# How can I be running out of address space on my 64-bit system?

Tags: technical-issues, supreme-commander

*Supreme Commander* seems to crash for almost everyone when set to max settings. [The general consensus is that the game is hitting the 2GB address space limit on Windows.](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2281) The quick fix is to increase Windows' address space limit from 2 to 3 GB. The solution is to switch to a 64-bit version of Windows.

The former did not work for me as the game still crashes. To make things more bizarre, I am already running a 64-bit version of Windows 7.

Why is my 64-bit OS running out of address space?

My specs:

- CPU: AMD Phenom II X4 970 Processor 3.50 GHz
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX460 SE (2 GB)
- RAM: 4GB

Comment: Offhand, do you know if the game is a 64-bit version? Because it won't go past the memory limits unless it was compiled 64-bit.

Comment: @CyberSkull I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: Can you check the properties of the executable? Getting info on it may say whether the build of the game you have is 32 or 64-bit native.

Comment: @CyberSkull and puk: For checking in an exe is 32 or 64 bit see [Quick way to tell if an installed application is 64-bit or 32-bit](http://superuser.com/q/103071/39366) on Super User. In short look for `*32` after the name in Task Manager's Processes tab or download an application to do it for you. I'd suspect it's 32bit though, as the vast majority of big name games being released even today are still 32bit.

Comment: @DMA57361 Thanks for the tip! What I wanted to see was whether a 64-bit build is even available to run. I'm not sure if the Windows [Portable Executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) supports multiple architectures per file like [Mach-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) does, so I want to know what version puk is launching.

Comment: @CyberSkull I don't think (but cannot find a reference to back me up...) that the PE format can encapsulate both a 32 and 64 bit version in a single file.

Comment: @DMA57361 From what I have seen in Linux, when you can't do multi-architecture binaries the developer typically labels them something like `Game_x86_32` and `Game_x86_64`. So the point I've been lamely trying to get to is there is no point in setting a high memory limit flag if the game can't use that much memory in the first place.

Comment: Indeed @CyberSkull, which is something I've also almost said in my answer. But, you *could* modify a 32bit `exe` to be Large Address Aware, which would potentially give it a little more (assuming it's not LAA already), but at the risk of being branded a cheater (hacked `exe`!) if you play multiplayer or if the game is handled by Steam's VAC, of whatever else is still about (which is why I'm not linking to anything, it's mildly dangerous so people can take that upon themselves if they really need to).

Comment: SupCom can be safely altered; Forged Alliance already is LAA. (IIRC)

Answer (score 6):

Enabling the `/3GB` switch on 32bit Windows won't allow a 32bit application to address more memory unless the application is Large Address Aware. If it *is* LAA, then a 32bit application could address up to 3GB when the switch is enabled.

Similarly, using 64bit Windows will not automatically allow a 32-bit application to address more memory, although a LAA 32bit application could address 4GB in this scenario.

So, the short answer to your headline question is: **Unless especially compiled as Large Address Aware, a 32bit application *cannot* address more than 2GB of memory, even on a 64bit OS and system (and even if LAA, the cap would still be 4GB on 64bit)**.

I suspect most applications are not released as LAA (for example, Skyrim wasn't LAA; they patched that in a few weeks after release), but I cannot comment on the `exe` provided with Supreme Commander.

---

There are tools available to patch in Large Address Aware flag to existing `exe`s (if the SC game's isn't), but be wary of using them on games as you risk tripping anti-cheat detectors (because your `exe` has been modified).

Also, have you monitored memory usage of the game and system when a crash occurs? Given you only have 4GB total in the system, could it be that you're simply running out of RAM for the entire system, and so the game or system chokes to death when it ends up being paged out to disk?

Comment: I have not monitored the memory usage, and apparently using System Monitor to do so is insufficient (I can't remember why). But if it was running out of memory it would slow down as it paged, not crash immediately to windows.

Comment: @puk it would *probably* slow down, yes, but it is possible for an application to be very intolerant of that sort of thing. Have you tried using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) for monitoring? At the very least if the game always crashes at roughly the same memory usage you can be sure that the problem is what you think it is.

Comment: @puk You may try [4GB Patch](http://www.ntcore.com/4gb_patch.php) by Ntcore to patch Supreme Commander's EXE file to have the LAA flag, and see if this prevents crashes. It will backup the original file before patching, so you can revert to the original EXE if anything goes wrong. This also worked with Skyrim, back when it was not yet patched to be Large Address Aware. If you have Forged Alliance (Supreme Commander's standalone expansion), then you won't need this patch, as it appears that Forged Alliance is already LAA (try searching for 'Forged Alliance LAA' in your favorite search engine).

Comment: @galacticninja it's the LAA issue. I patched it using Visual Studio and it worked. The best thing to do, though, is get FA

Answer (score 2):

I went to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\supreme commander\bin\SupremeCommander.exe` » right clicked on `SupremeCommander.exe` » Troubleshoot compatibility.

It automatically suggested Windows XP SP2 compatibility mode, I accepted it, and now it's running OK under Windows 7 64-bit.